# Method cannot be applied to given types, trying to call my getMenuChoice() method

Tags: java

I'm trying to call my getMenuChoice() method in my main method to output the things in my getMenuChoice() method but it is telling me that the method cannot be applied to the given types;   required: String, String             found: no arguments

Why is this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
 package footballgame;

 import java.util.Scanner;




 public class FootballGame {
 static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     String footballTeam1;
     String footballTeam2;

     System.out.print("Enter a name for a team:");
     footballTeam1 = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Enter a name for another team:");
     footballTeam2 = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Game Score:");
     System.out.println(footballTeam1 + ":0");
     System.out.println(footballTeam2 + ":0");

     choice = getMenuChoice();
   }
 public static String getMenuChoice(String footballTeam1,String footballTeam2){
     String choice;


     do{
     System.out.println("Select an option:");
     System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + "scored");
     System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + "scored");
     System.out.println("C: game ended.");
     System.out.println("?:");
     choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            choice = (footballTeam1);
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
            choice = (footballTeam2);
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
            choice = ("Game over!");
        }


        }while(!choice.equals("A") && !choice.equals("B") && !choice.equals("C"));
        return choice;



        }


        }
```

Here is my new code.

```
package footballgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballGame { static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
String choice;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String footballTeam1;
String footballTeam2;

System.out.print("Enter a name for a team:");
footballTeam1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter a name for another team:");
footballTeam2 = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Game Score:");
System.out.println(footballTeam1 + ":0");
System.out.println(footballTeam2 + ":0");

choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
}
public static String getMenuChoice(String footballTeam1,String footballTeam2){
String choice;
String input;


do{
    System.out.println("Select an option:");
    System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + " scored");
    System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + " scored");
    System.out.println("C: game ended.");
    System.out.println("?:");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
        choice = (footballTeam1);
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
        choice = (footballTeam2);
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
        choice = ("Game over!");
    }


}while(!input.equals("A") && !input.equals("B") && !input.equals("C"));
return choice;



}
}
```

Here's the my other class with the addscore method within it at the bottom.
    public class FootballTeam {

```
private String name;
private int score;
public static int TOUCHDOWN = 6;
public static int FIELD_GOAL = 3;
public static int SAFETY = 2;
public static int TWO_POINT_CONVERSION = 2;
public static int EXTRA_POINT = 1;

public FootballTeam(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public boolean addScore(int points) {
    if (points == TOUCHDOWN || points == FIELD_GOAL || points == SAFETY || points ==     TWO_POINT_CONVERSION || points == EXTRA_POINT) {
        score = points + score;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your problem would be that you don't have parameters when you call `getMenuChoice()`. Change it so that you have two input parameters: `footballTeam1` and `footballTeam2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two String argument to `getMenuChoice();` method.

Need to change

```
choice = getMenuChoice();
```

to

```
String choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1 ,footballTeam2);

System.out.println("Choice is :" + choice );
```

**update**

You are using && operator in your while condition that's not correct.

Replace with below one

```
while (!choice.equals("A") || !choice.equals("B")
                ||  !choice.equals("C"));
```

Once you found the matched value then no need to iterate again, You can return the matched value.

Your corrected method is below

```
public static String getMenuChoice(String footballTeam1,
        String footballTeam2) {
    String choice;

    do {
        System.out.println("Select an option:");
        System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + "scored");
        System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + "scored");
        System.out.println("C: game ended.");
        System.out.println("?:");
        Scanner keyboard = null;
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            return footballTeam1;
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            return footballTeam2;
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            return "Game over!";
        }

    } while (!choice.equals("A") || !choice.equals("B")
            ||  !choice.equals("C"));
    return choice;

}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, now its giving me an error on choice, telling me that it cannot find the symbol choice.  All I want it to do is call that method and output what is in it.

Comment: Ah alright, now it keeps displaying the menu in my output, even though I input the correct letter or not. It's like it is infinitely going through the loop and keeps displaying it. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You declared `getMenuChoice(String footballTeam1,String footballTeam2)`

That means that when calling this method you **must** give two `String` parameters:

```
choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
```

BTW, choice is not declared. You need to declare it before (or when) assigning value to it:

```
String choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
```

Comment: Ah alright, now it keeps displaying the menu in my output, even though I input the correct letter or not. It's like it is infinitely going through the loop and keeps displaying it. Why is that?

Comment: How about debugging it? Use a debugger or print some values that can help you.

Comment: Hint - think about your do-while condition. Check what choice is when you enter A, B or C.

Comment: Trying to do that currently, never used it before sadly.

Comment: Ok, I'll upload the new code now. I'm getting an error that I didn't initiate choice now though, when I think I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Game Score:");
System.out.println(footballTeam1 + ":0");
System.out.println(footballTeam2 + ":0");

choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1,footballTeam2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Run this code:

package footballgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballGame { static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String footballTeam1;
        String footballTeam2;

        System.out.print("Enter a name for a team:");
        footballTeam1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a name for another team:");
        footballTeam2 = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Game Score:");
        System.out.println(footballTeam1 + ":0");
        System.out.println(footballTeam2 + ":0");

        choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
    }
    public static String getMenuChoice(String footballTeam1,String footballTeam2){
        String choice ="";
        String input;


        do{
            System.out.println("Select an option:");
            System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + " scored");
            System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + " scored");
            System.out.println("C: game ended.");
            System.out.println("?:");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                choice = (footballTeam1);
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                choice = (footballTeam2);
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                choice = ("Game over!");
            }


        }while(!input.equals("A") && !input.equals("B") && !input.equals("C"));
        return choice;



    }
}





And the log is:
A is what you need input

Enter a name for a team:A

Enter a name for another team:A

Game Score:

A:0

A:0

Select an option:

A:A scored

B:A scored

C: game ended.

?:

A  //------------this place is what you need input to stop loop.


Process finished with exit code 0


Hand socre:
package footballgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballTeam {
    private String name;
    private int score;
    public static int TOUCHDOWN = 6;
    public static int FIELD_GOAL = 3;
    public static int SAFETY = 2;
    public static int TWO_POINT_CONVERSION = 2;
    public static int EXTRA_POINT = 1;
    static  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public FootballTeam() {

    }
    public FootballTeam(String name, int score) {

        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {

        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {

        this.score = score;
    }

    public boolean addScore(int points) {

        if (points == TOUCHDOWN || points == FIELD_GOAL || points == SAFETY || points == TWO_POINT_CONVERSION || points == EXTRA_POINT) {
            score = points + score;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getName() + ":" + this.getScore();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice;

        FootballTeam teamA = new FootballTeam();
        FootballTeam teamB = new FootballTeam();


        System.out.print("Enter a name for a team A:");
        teamA.setName(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter a name for another team B :");
        teamB.setName(keyboard.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter a source for a team A :");
        teamA.setScore(Integer.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine()));
        System.out.print("Enter a name for another team B:");
        teamB.setScore(Integer.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Game Score:");
        System.out.println(teamA.getName() + ":" + teamA.getScore());
        System.out.println(teamB.getName() + ":" + teamB.getScore());

        choice = getMenuChoice(teamA, teamB);
        System.out.println(choice);
    }
    public static String getMenuChoice(FootballTeam teamA, FootballTeam teamB){
        String choice ="";
        String input;


        do{
            System.out.println("Select an option:");
            System.out.println("A:" + teamA.getName() + " scored");
            System.out.println("A:" + teamA.getName() + " scored");
            System.out.println("C: game ended.");
            System.out.println("?:");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                choice = teamA.toString();
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                choice = teamB.toString();
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                choice = ("Game over!");
            }


        }while(!input.equals("A") && !input.equals("B") && !input.equals("C"));
        return choice;



    }


}
```

Comment: Yes that worked, and that's what I have, but it keeps looping even after I input a correct value.

Comment: What you input:  I attached my log for you:

Comment: Enter a name for a team:A
Enter a name for another team:A
Game Score:
A:0
A:0
Select an option:
A:Ascored
B:Ascored
C: game ended.
?:
{A}
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Because you have choice = keyboard.nextLine(); So you need input A after "C: game ended","?:"

Comment: I've sinced changed my code and edited it into my original code, I changed my input to input instead of choice, to try and get it to stop looping

Comment: What do you mean by I need to input A after "C:game ender", "?:" ?

Comment: Can you see my code. you need input A in console in here: A //------------this place is what you need input to stop loop.

Comment: Yeah thats where I need it to stop, after the user inputs that letter, but how do I do that? I'm sorry, I'm confused :/

Comment: IF you're not busy, could you help me set up a parameter of a different method? It's confusing me.

Comment: Actually I am not sure what you base on you method. Can you explain more detail for "set up a parameter of a different method"? That i can help you

Comment: so I need to make another method, handleTeamScoring() method. this method must accept one FootballTeam as a paramater and must do the following, it must ask the user how many points the team scored, it must accept the number of points scored from the user using the Scanner keyboard. It must try to add the number of points entered using the team's addscore() method which is a method from another class I have, I can upload it in the original post, which will return true if the number of points is valid or false if it isnt.

Comment: It will also repeat the first two steps until the user enters a number of points that addScore() method can accept. I've uploaded the addscore method to the original post.

Comment: Yes, I got you code. but still no sure what you want, I can see FootballTeam class.  If you can write Pseudo-code and then help you go though, that better. because I have no idea for the logic side.

Comment: I need to write a new method called handleTeamScoring()

Comment: I add change method, but not sure is that you want.